# I installed basic MiKTeX and failed to synchronize from MiKTeX package manager

Tags: errors, miktex

MiKTeX problem report dialog box provides following error. However the file is present.

> Invalid argument: path="C:\Users\swati\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le\df2c24cb21984fa85003c1ecc818ff83.fndb"

Both the file and directory have read and write access. My OS is Windows 10.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide us with some context. When does this error message show up (what are you trying to do). Is there some further log?

Comment: I installed basic-miktex-2.9.6361-x64.exe in my windows 10 laptop and then opened MikTex package manager and selected Synchronize. I received the above error in a dialog box. I checked and gave read write permission to all files and folders under MiKTex under Local and tried again with similar results. The file and the path are however very much present.

Comment: Further to my error in MikTex package manager, I ran MikTex Package Manager (Admin). However it ended with another problem report, before even starting

Windows API error 87: The parameter is incorrect. 

Data
path="C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le\1756f6ade37d5f870f23c05a7f81e257.fndb"

Comment: Can you update the fndb (miktex settings (user + admin), button "refresh FNDB")?

Answer (score 0):

This is often caused by another MikTex process running at the same time. Close any other MikTex processes (or just reboot) and try again.